# How to retrieve an element of a list of enumerated tuples by its enumeration?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list which looks as follows:

```
vertices = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),...]
```

And I enumerate it using "enumerate":

```
list(enumerate(vertices))
```

The list then looks as follows:

```
[(1,(1,2)),(2,(3,4)),(3,(5,6)),...]
```

I would like to know if this is the way in python to create a "map" and which is the best way to retrieve a vertex by providing the index. (e.g. providing 1 I would like to receive (1,2), providing 2 I would like to receive (3,4)...)

Comment: do you know about dictionaries in python? That's what you want basically.

Comment: not yet but thanks will look it up

Comment: You can access list items by their index already: `vertices[0]`  `vertices[2]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just switch to using the `dict` constructor instead of `list`:

```
d = dict(enumerate(vertices))
```

which will result:

```
{0: (1, 2), 1: (3, 4), 2: (5, 6)}
```

Then you can access the items:

```
print(d[1])
(3, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to dict

```
my_dict = dict([(1,(1,2)),(2,(3,4)),(3,(5,6)),...])
```

and you can access by index:

```
my_dict[1]
(1,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost there:

```
dict(enumerate(vertices))
```